# 'Flutter build ios' fails when dependencies are added

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

Starting from nothing, I...

1. create new flutter app in Android Studio
2. add font_awesome_flutter dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.12.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

3. Run app on andriod simulator, runs fine BUT
4. Run app on iOS simulator, get this error:

```
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:342:in `rescue in load': Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat), ActiveSupport::Multibyte is unusable (IOError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:339:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:330:in `codepoints'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:152:in `block in decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `inject'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:278:in `normalize'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `open'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:330:in `codepoints'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:152:in `block in decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `inject'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:278:in `normalize'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:342:in `rescue in load': Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat), ActiveSupport::Multibyte is unusable (IOError)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:339:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:330:in `codepoints'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:152:in `block in decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `inject'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:278:in `normalize'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `open'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:340:in `load'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:330:in `codepoints'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:152:in `block in decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `inject'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:141:in `decompose'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:278:in `normalize'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

Tried running flutter doctor, flutter clean, deleting pods file, setting the development team in XCode. Nada.

I've also tried this with multiple dependencies in multiple projects, with the same result. For some reason, my dev environment is not letting me run XCode projects at all. The problem always arises as soon as I add a dependency and run flutter build ios, or try to run on ios simulator. I'm not sure where to look or how to begin to correct this. I am brand new to flutter and mobile development. I'm running iOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading flutter 1.17.5 to flutter 1.22, Have you recently upgraded your flutter SDK? For me this worked.

I removed the `ios/Flutter` folder from my directory and ran these commands and changed my **deployment target to 11.0**

```
-> flutter create .
-> flutter pub cache repair
-> cd ios 
-> pod init 
-> pod install
```

After following these commands, I could build the iOS on the simulator and also create the archive.

For a safer side get a backup of the deleted folder

Comment: I have recently upgraded to Flutter 2.0.1! Unfortunately after following these steps the issue is persisting. So do you think it's an issue with the Flutter upgrades?

Comment: Yes, I do think it because of the flutter upgrade. As before that things where working fine for me..

Comment: Try downgrading your flutter to 1.22